# Logging to a file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm using the following .xml configuration to log to the console and also to a file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/log.log" filePattern="${basePath}/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The problem is when I use the following code I get logs on the console but nothing is written to a file.

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
logger.error("Start App");
```

Also sometimes I get the following messages when I debug:

[image]
[image]

Note: when I print out `System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile")` I get null

Comment: what is the name of your `log4j2` configuration file and where it is placed ?

Comment: Are you certain you're looking in the correct file system path? Your basePath is set to "/logs" which is an absolute path not a relative path.